# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to save and Excel file to my database. I get this error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

This is my controller post method:

```java
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<DocumentCreateResponse> addDocument(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    Path copyLocation = Paths.get(uploadDir, Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()));
    Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), copyLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    Document savedDocument = documentService.save(copyLocation.toAbsolutePath().toFile());
    if (savedDocument == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new DocumentCreateResponse(null), null, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new DocumentCreateResponse(savedDocument.getId()), null, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

This is document class:

```java
@Entity
public class DocumentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="document_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name ="document_file")
    private File file;


    public DocumentEntity() {
    }

    public DocumentEntity(File file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

And this is my schema creation file (I use Flyway and PostgreSQL)

```sql
create table if not exists document_entity
(
    document_id bigserial
    constraint document_entity_document_id
    not null primary key,
    document_file varchar not null
);
```

Where should I add change, to let my files save properly and not cause this error? I have read articles and seen this error, but I do not see what should I change in my code.

```java
public class DocumentService implements DocumentServicePort {
    private final DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    public DocumentService(DocumentRepository documentRepository) {
        this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Document save(File file) {
        Document document = new Document(file);
        if (document.hasValidExtension(document)) {
            documentRepository.saveDocument(document);
            return document;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your repository class too. what's the implementation of `documentService.save`

Comment: I add  documentService class to post, documentRepository has only one method Document save(Document document);

Comment: method hasValidExtension checks if extension is correct , if not it does not returns document

Comment: are you using JPA to save or query?

Comment: I am using JPA .

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your file as varchar in database, where in your application you've declared that field as File.

You can do a few things, but for the case you've mentioned, change the type of the column in database. It should be 'bytea`

run this on db (better if the table is empty):

```
ALTER TABLE document_entity ALTER COLUMN document_file TYPE bytea USING document_file::TEXT::BYTEA;
```

Comment: It does not work, still get the same error. I even deleted database and set it up again, and it didnt work

Comment: yes it is, So i dont have a clue whats going on

Comment: have you checked whether the column type was updated to bytea?

Comment: use `@Lob` annotation to your file field in entity class, and change the variable type to `byte[]`